# Django models - how to create a selected_instance field from an instance in a collection

Tags: django-models

Django noob questions:

I want to create a site which allows users to share info about cars.  Each car should have a collection of images, and the submitter should select one of the images to be used to represent the car on a listing page.  A basic set of models is shown below:

```
class Manufacturer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class ModelBrand(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class Car(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False)

    # identifying information
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(Manufacturer)
    model_brand = models.ForeignKey(ModelBrand)
    model_year = models.PositiveIntegerField()


class CarImage(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False)
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car, related_name='images')
    source_url = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    image = ImageField(upload_to='cars')
```

But how do I model the selected image?  Do I put a 'selected' BooleanField on the CarImage class?  And how do I configure the Car and CarImage admin classes to allow an admin site user to select and image for a car from its 'images' collection?

Answer (score 0):

First, I would like to suggest you to refactor your class using an auxiliary TimeStampedClass

```
class TimeStampedModel(models.Model):
    """
    Abstract class model that saves timestamp of creation and updating of a model.
    Each model used in the project has to subclass this class.
    """

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        ordering = ('-created_on',)
```

So you can use this class over your project, subclassing it.
One simple solution for your question is attach your image gallery to your car, and create one attribute that is a IntegerField that stores the picture position in the image gallery:

```
...

class CarImage(TimeStampedField):

    source_url = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    image = ImageField(upload_to='cars')

class Car(TimeStampedModel):

    image_gallery = models.ManyToManyField(CarImage)
    selected_picture = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    # identifying information
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(Manufacturer)
    model_brand = models.ForeignKey(ModelBrand)
    model_year = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

So, if selected_picture is n, you just need to get n-th picture inside image_gallery